# Binary Comparison of two pairs of strings using Select Case in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have 20 sets of two pairs of strings that can be anywhere from 1 to 5 characters each. Most of the time they are actually integers between 1 and 52, or sometimes a floating point number with one decimal place between 1 and 53 (eg 52.3 would be the maximum value). On occasion, a greater than or less than symbol is used and will bump up the maximum number of characters to 5 (eg >26.2).

These groups of 20 sets are going to be compared a large number of times (on the order of 25k or so meaning ~ 500K of the single comparisons like the one below). My guess is the best storage option would be a string rather than testing it each time to see if its a string, integer or floating point (but if I am wrong please correct me). The strings can be paired in any manner (eg a duplicate is allowed in a pair)

I will show one set of the 20 as an example:

> 1. 12 13
> 2. 13 14

Lets use letters to represent them A, B, C and D so we don't lose sight of the fact that they are strings and see how they compare.  A = 12, B = 13 and C = 14...in this example there is no D but there could be in others.

> 1. AB
> 2. BC

Now that we see this, we can extrapolate to 10 possible ways that they can match up and 3 possible ways in which they won't...and depending on how they share, one of 7 values is returned from a dictionary, collection, or index, array or whatever, like this.

> 1. AA AA (share both doubly get index value 1)
> 2. AA AB (share 1st doubly get index value 2)
> 3. AA BA (share 1st doubly get index value 2)
> 4. AB AA (share 1st doubly get index value 2)
> 5. AB BB (share 2nd doubly get index value 3)
> 6. AB AB (share 2 get index value 4)
> 7. AB AC (share 1st one time get index value 5)
> 8. AB CA (share 1st one time get index value 5)
>
> **9.  AB BC (share 2nd one time get index value 6)**
>
> 10. AB CB (share 2nd one time get index value 6)
> 11. AA BC (share none get index value 7)
> 12. AB CD (share none get index value 7)
> 13. AB CC (share none get index value 7)

In the above example of 12,13 and 13,14 number nine in the list would be the comparative result and I would need to get the index value of 6.

Setting aside how I'm getting the index value, or how these sets come up, I want to focus on the logic to decide which index value to return.  I tried a large nested If - Ifelse and it was monumentally slow (on the order of 7 hours for 500k comparisons).  I figured the next step was to do a nested select case which I will show here:

```
For i = 0 To 20    
Select Case A
    Case B
        Select Case A
            Case C
                Select Case A
                    Case D                                                     
                        'code to get AAAA index value 1
                    Case Else                                                                   
                        'code to get AAAB index value 2
                End Select
            Case Else
                Select Case A
                    Case D                                                        
                        'code to get AABA index value 2
            Case Else
            'code to get AABC index value 7
                End Select
        End Select
    Case Else
        Select Case A
            Case C
                Select Case A
                    Case D                                                     
                        'code to get ABAA index value 2
                    Case Else 
                        Select Case B
                            Case D                                             
                                'code to get ABAB index value 4
                            Case Else                                                           
                                'code to get ABAC index value 5
                        End Select
                End Select
            Case Else
                Select Case B
                    Case C
                        Select Case B
                            Case D                                             
                                'code to get ABBB index value 3
                            Case Else                                                           
                                'code to get ABBC index value 6
                        End Select
                    Case Else
                        Select Case A
                            Case D                                             
                                'code to get ABCA index value 5
                            Case Else
                                Select Case B
                                    Case D                                     
                                       'code to get ABCB index value 6
                                    Case Else   
                                        'all thats left code to get ABCD and ABCC index value 7 
                                End Select
                        End Select
                End Select
        End Select
End Select
Next i
```

Again...monumentally slow. I've tried this by storing the strings individually, in arrays, dictionaries, class objects and iterating through them to try to optimize the comparison to no avail. I THINK I've got it nailed down to this comparison being what's causing the problem. Don't get me wrong. For 1 set of 20, its lightening fast, but when I need to do it 50,000 times, it takes 7 hours.

The thing I haven't tried yet but am mildly interested in is external vbscript or C++ multi threading code for the comparison (I don't know anything about vbscipt C++ or multithreading so at the moment this is out of the question. So how about it?  Any suggestions on how I can speed the comparison up?

Comment: Sorry, completely don't understand your question - I think you lost me already when you mentioned the decimal and the greater/less than signs.

Comment: Each is a data point in a large set. Each point could be an integer value 1, 2, 3 up 52 or a floating point value 1.1, 1.2...52.2 and then sometimes <,> could be part of the data point <10, >26.2. Thus I’m choosing to use a data type string.

Comment: ...and I want to compare two pairs of them.

Comment: This would probably be a better fit for [codereview.se], if you included the whole code (not just the loop body, and not just placeholders).

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I will consider this, thanks!

Comment: So `>26.2` could be your `A` (or `B`...) and is something different than `26` or `26.2` or `>26`?

Comment: @FunThomas yes and what I’m trying to do is compare them to see which ones match up say 26,26 and 26,27 being situation AA AB in the table of 13

Comment: Note that if you post this question exactly as-is on CR, it will be shot down as "hypothetical code" - make sure you include the whole thing, not placehlder comments. There's a non-zero chance that lots of inefficiencies are happening in whatever these comments stand for.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I realize this.  I appreciate your suggestion and input very much. The rest of my code works, is quite lengthy and as far as I can tell is working quickly, leaving the comparison portion as that which is bogging everything down.  I was just hoping maybe someone had a more efficient way to compare two pairs of strings like this.

Comment: Sorry @FunThomas yes yes >26 will be something different than 26.3 or 27  or anything else in the data set

Comment: @Dan a `Select Case` gets converted into an `If` in the compiler IIRC so writing as such probably won't see any speed benefits

Comment: Dang I had read that select case could be an improvement.

Comment: FWIW it's extremely hard to follow the nested logic and understand what's supposed to happen. CR feedback would absolutely include "extract each branch into its own, meaningfully named procedure".

Comment: Thanks!  I think I may be stuck looking for an external multi thread solution...that’s what I’m hearing from some other folks anyway. When I figure out go to do that, I’ll post a solution.  I appreciate all the input

Comment: Indeed, you can make a COM-visible C# or VB.NET type library that your VBA project can reference and invoke, then have multithreaded .NET code do the hard work and return an `ArrayList` with the results. C++ might work too, and will spare the COM interop overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tinkered an example code. It basically creates a code 4-digit code string from 4 input parameters and then looks up in a static dictionary which value is assigned to the code. Have not tested is with all variations though.

In a test, 500.000 iterations run in less than 2 seconds. This will increase depending how you read all your strings, but the comparison itself is not the issue.

You will need a reference to the scripting library

```
Option Explicit
Dim codeTab As Dictionary

Sub test()
    Debug.Print getCode("12", "13", "13", "14")
End Sub

Sub initTab()
    Set codeTab = New Dictionary
    codeTab.Add "AAAA", 1
    codeTab.Add "AAAB", 2
    codeTab.Add "AABA", 2
    codeTab.Add "ABAA", 2
    codeTab.Add "ABBB", 3
    codeTab.Add "ABAB", 4
    codeTab.Add "ABAC", 5
    codeTab.Add "ABCA", 5
    codeTab.Add "ABBC", 6
    codeTab.Add "ABCB", 6
    codeTab.Add "AABC", 7
    codeTab.Add "ABCD", 7
    codeTab.Add "ABCC", 7
End Sub

Function getCode(p1 As String, p2 As String, p3 As String, p4 As String) As Integer

    Dim p(), code As String, nextFree As String
    ' Create an array out of the parameters to enable looping.
    p = Array(p1, p2, p3, p4)
    code = ""
    nextFree = "A"
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    For i = 0 To 3   ' loop over all 4 values
        Dim found As Boolean: found = False
        For j = 0 To i - 1    ' compare the value with previous values
            If p(i) = p(j) Then     ' value already there, add matching letter
                found = True
                code = code & Mid(code, j + 1, 1)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        If Not found Then    ' new value, use next free letter
            code = code & nextFree
            nextFree = Chr(Asc(nextFree) + 1)
        End If
    Next i

    ' Debug.Print code
    getCode = codeTab(code)
End Function
```

Comment: This is a beautifully elegant piece of code. It works a little faster than what I have written and is much more masterful. If you do not mind I am going to use it and start incorporating things like it in my code. I have broken my program down a little further and found that you and @MathieuGuinedon are correct. This wasn’t my problem. The biggest time suck is coming from an ADO connection and recset retrieval with an SQL stored procedure for each new set of 20. I’ll repost in the DBA with the relevant code and stored query if you’re interested....I’ll link it here in my next comment.

Comment: Actually didn’t need the DBA forum.  It was my table structure.  I had 20 tables for each of the 20 sets. I put them all into one table and got 7 hours down to 10 minutes.  I still like your answer @FunThomas and have incorporated it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only posting this because I said earlier that I would.  I posed my question to the database Administrators forum and after some suggestions ended up answering my own question. I am content to leave @FunThomas's answer because he answered at least what I was looking for at the time and hopefully it helps others.  I have however solved doing this binary comparison using three tables, a set of derived tables and a bunch of joins. 67,000 comparisons in 5 seconds.  Im sure I can speed this up with more indices and optimizing the sql and any front end code.  Thanks for all your help!

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/231866/comparing-two-pairs-of-columns-between-two-tables-and-returning-the-column-from/232370#232370.

I'll move it back to edit the post in a bit.  I just wanted those that were following to notice in case they wanted to have a look.